# azure sdk link certificate into new resource group

Tags: c#, azure, ssl, sdk, certificate

I'm migrating from ARM Template to C# Azure SDK deployment option and have a problem to translate the use of existing certificate into new resource group.
I have a SSL Certificate stored into a specific Resource group and Keyvault.
I have 3 environments into 3 other resource groups created with ARM template that use this certificate (webapps ssl bindings).
When I go into my certificate from azure portal, I can see the private certificate is linked to my 3 resource groups

This chunk of JSON imports the ssl certificate into the new resource group

```
{
      "type": "Microsoft.Web/certificates",
      "name": "MyCert",
      "apiVersion": "2016-03-01",
      "location": "[variables('Location')]",
      "properties": {
        "keyVaultId": "[parameters('keyvaultId')]",
        "keyVaultSecretName": "[parameters('KeyvaultSecretName')]",
        "thumbprint": "[parameters('certThumbprint')]"
      },
      "dependsOn": [
        "[concat('Microsoft.Web/serverfarms/', variables('WebAppAppPlanName'))]"
      ],
    },
```

Using this chunk of json create ssl bindings through its thumbprint :

```
{
      "name": "[concat(variables('WebAppName'),'/',variables('subDomain'), '.domain.fr')]",
      "apiVersion": "2016-08-01",
      "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites/hostNameBindings",
      "location": "[variables('Location')]",
      "dependsOn": [
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/sites', variables('WebAppName'))]"
      ],
      "tags": {
        "displayName": "HostName"
      },
      "properties": {
        "siteName": "[variables('WebAppName')]",
        "customHostNameDnsRecordType": "CName",
        "hostNameType": "Verified",
        "sslState": "SniEnabled",
        "thumbprint": "[reference(resourceId('Microsoft.Web/certificates', 'CertName')).Thumbprint]"
      }
    },
```

Now I'm trying to create the same thing with Azure SDK :

```
 webApp = webApp.Update()
                  .DefineHostnameBinding()
                  .WithThirdPartyDomain(domain)
                  .WithSubDomain(subdomain)
                  .WithDnsRecordType(CustomHostNameDnsRecordType.CName)
                  .Attach()
                  .Apply();

            webApp = webApp.Update()
                        .WithThirdPartyHostnameBinding(domain, subdomain)
                        .DefineSslBinding()
                            .ForHostname(hostName)
                            .WithExistingCertificate(certificateThumbPrint)
                            .WithSniBasedSsl()
                            .Attach()
                        .Apply();
```

This code does not work because of certificateThumbprint not found into my newly created resource group.
What is missing is the equivalent of the first json chunk to link my certificate to my resource group. 
Using azure portal and doing this manually is called "Import App Service Certificate"

How can I programmatically, with azure SDK in C#, import my existing app service certificate into my new resource group ?

Comment: I think you need to create the certificate first. Take a look at the method [BeginCreateOrUpdateCertificate](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.management.websites.appservicecertificateordersoperationsextensions.begincreateorupdatecertificate?view=azure-dotnet#Microsoft_Azure_Management_WebSites_AppServiceCertificateOrdersOperationsExtensions_BeginCreateOrUpdateCertificate_Microsoft_Azure_Management_WebSites_IAppServiceCertificateOrdersOperations_System_String_System_String_System_String_Microsoft_Azure_Management_WebSites_Models_AppServiceCertificateResource_).

Comment: I already have my certificate into my keyvault.
I need to reuse it by importing this app certificate into my new resource group before creating ssl bindings (the last code block with the two updates)

Comment: Just take a look. The method means to create a resource with type Microsoft.Web/certificates.

Comment: I checked your link but I don't really understand the real purpose of this function. Does it create a new certificate ? does it create only a "link" ? there is no example of how implementing it. It only says "Creates or updates a certificate and associates with key vault secret.". 
Can you just add a little explanation please ? I tried to search some documentations, examples, use cases for this method but there is no result

Comment: I think the way to create the appcertificate into my new resource group is here :

`var certificate = azure.AppServices.AppServiceCertificates
                .Define($"CertName")
                .WithRegion(ResourcesHelper.Location)
                .WithExistingResourceGroup(RG)
                .WithPfxByteArray(pfx)
                .WithPfxPassword(pwd)
                .Create();
`

The difficulty now is to get the PFX and Password from my keyvault... I tried many things but nothing works

Comment: just tried with this : 
getting CertificateOrder from azure.AppServices.AppServiceCertificateOrders
then I use WithExistingCertificateOrder instead of WithPfxByteArray
ValidationException : password cannot be null.
There is no way to specify a password. 
How can it be done ? there is no documentation about it

Comment: How do you create that certificate? I can the password property in the Azure template and there is also the method `withPfxPassword(String password)` in `AppServiceCertificate.DefinitionStages.WithPfxFilePassword`.

Comment: The certificate has been created 2 years ago through azure portal (manually) and is stored into a separate resource group containing the SSL app service certificate (wildcard) + a keyvault with only one secret (which stores private key I suppose). All this stuff has been created automatically by azure portal user interface.

I already tried the WithPfxPassword method but can't manage to make it work... and I have never been asked to input a password when I created de certificate.That's the point.

Answer (score 0):

When trying to import an existing certificate to an app service from a key vault, You need to add/link the key vault certificate to the resource group first.

[To do this with Azure REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/appservice/certificates/createorupdate)

When using old Azure SDK ([Microsoft.Azure.Management.WebSites](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.management.websites.appservicecertificateordersoperationsextensions.begincreateorupdatecertificate?view=azure-dotnet#Microsoft_Azure_Management_WebSites_AppServiceCertificateOrdersOperationsExtensions_BeginCreateOrUpdateCertificate_Microsoft_Azure_Management_WebSites_IAppServiceCertificateOrdersOperations_System_String_System_String_System_String_Microsoft_Azure_Management_WebSites_Models_AppServiceCertificateResource_)), there is a class available BeginCreateOrUpdateCertificate to do this operation. But Microsoft is not recommending using it as it may get deprecated soon.

With Azure fluent SDK - there is no way we can achieve this using the default app certificate management Class.
"Microsoft.Azure.Management.Fluent.Azure.AppServices.AppServiceCertificates.Define()".

However, there is a class named RestClient in "Microsoft.Azure.Management.ResourceManager.Fluent.Core" namespace that is designed to call azure APIs manually. And we can make use of [WebSiteManagementClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.management.appservice.fluent.websitemanagementclient?view=azure-dotnet) that uses the RestClient to make rest API calls against web app resources.

```
var restClient = Microsoft.Azure.Management.ResourceManager.Fluent.Core.RestClient.Configure().WithEnvironment(AzureEnvironment.AzureGlobalCloud).WithCredentials(credentials).Build();
        
        
var x = new WebSiteManagementClient(restClient);
x.SubscriptionId = "your-subscription-id";
var result = x.Certificates.CreateOrUpdateAsync(resourceGroupName, "UploadTest", new CertificateInner("your certificate-location (East-US)",
                        "certificate-password (pass string.Empty if null)",                            
                        keyVaultId: "/subscriptions/your-subscription-id/resourcegroups/your-resourcegroup-id/providers/microsoft.keyvault/vaults/your-key-vault-id",
                        keyVaultSecretName: "key-vault-secretname", hostNames: new List<string>() { "hostname" })).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

This will add/link the existing certificate in the key vault to the resource group and will be available for the app service to use.